# How we get the data from csv file by defining the where condition?

Tags: php, laravel, csv

I want to get the data from the CSV file by defining the where condition in laravel I already have a function for this and this will properly get the data on an array $customerArr But I want to use where condition All data come from city_master.csv file were heading is define as City Code.Means that I want matching data from CSV file not from the database.
The code is here-

```
$file = public_path('file/city_master.csv');
$customerArr = $this->csvToArray($file);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($customerArr); $i++)
{
//dd($customerArr );
$userreg = $customerArr->where('City_Code', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')->get();
}
return 'not in array';
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `where` on a PHP array, are you returning a collection from your `csvToArray` method? If you do, then you should not be calling `get()` on the collection as this is a code for the query builder.

So I will assume that you are returning just an array from your method, then to make a collection you can use the helper function, so your code can become the following:

```
$file = public_path('file/city_master.csv');
$customerArr = $this->csvToArray($file);

$result = collect($customerArr)->filter(function ($item) use ($query) {
    // replace stristr with your choice of matching function
    return false !== stristr($item->City_Code, $query);
});

if($result->count()) {
    // success
}

return 'not in array';
```

I use [stristr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php) function to emulate a LIKE operator.

Answer (score 0):

Also you have a count function in the loop itself; count($customerArr) is being unnecessarily evaluated every time the loop cycles. Store the count in a variable and use that instead, which will improve your execution time.

```
$count = count($customerArr);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
{
//dd($customerArr );
$userreg = $customerArr->where('City_Code', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')->get();
}
```